# Analyze iOS App Power Usage

Tags: ios

My app currently shows up at around top 5 in power usage under settings->Battery. On that screen it says the app spends many hours in the background. Ive tried using Instruments however the analytics provided are not enough to draw any meaningful conclusions or pinpoint any sections of code. Any suggestions how to further investigate power consumption. A tool that ties power consumption to specific source code would be the best?

Answer (score 2):

I would use Xcode Instruments - Energy Diagnostics for what your looking for.

The process is - Open instruments and load the "Energy Diagnostics" template.  From there, you record data in instruments and use the app.  After your finished you can analyze the data.

Also, right in Xcode you can use the Energy Debug Tool now:

> Debug Energy During Development
>
> The debug navigator in Xcode includes an Energy Impact gauge, which
>   provides a high-level overview of energy usage as you test your app.
>   Consult this gauge regularly throughout your app’s testing cycle to
>   assess your app’s energy impact and identify potential problem areas
>   up-front. If necessary, dive into Instruments for more in-depth
>   analysis.

[image]

This will give you a good starting point to diagnose, from there you may need to look and analyze deeper (Activity Monitor, File Activity, Time Profiler, etc..) in Instruments.

Here is a [User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MeasuringEnergyImpact.html) from Apple on how to do this in greater detail and it also shows how to analyze the data using Instruments.

Comment: Is there any way to know the power consumption of our app ?

Comment: @VineeshTP other than energy logs from instruments you can also get power consumption of any specific app from the iPhone settings. For that, you need to use the battery power while using the app also for a reasonable amount of time I guess
Settings>battery
Wait a moment for Battery Usage to populate
you'll be able to see power consumption by different apps (in foreground and background)

Comment: @VineeshTP - Disclaimer, I'm an engineer at GameBench, but we've got a Desktop App that shows the mA power consumption of your app on iOS (plug-and-play, just connect the iOS device to a windows/linux/mac PC and follow the instructions)