# Reduce battery drain due to background activity programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, battery, xcode-instruments

I tried to use the Energy Log, Network Activity Log etc.., But these tools giving the graphs combining my app with other apps even though I selected my app in the instruments setup. I need to find my individual app battery drain due to background activity.

Is there any alternatives to Instruments in Xcode or process/ steps to find and reduce the battery drain when app is in background mode.

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MeasuringEnergyImpact.html), to measure the energy impact for a single iOS application, you should remember to both set the `Target device` and `Target app`. To choose the application you need to inspect, it needs to be available on the `Target device` prior to when you start profiling. If not, you will not see the application appear in the list of `Target app`s.

After you have set the appropriate `Target device` and `Target app`, simply start profiling by clicking the circular and red `Record` button (or press `Command-R`).

Comment: I did the Target Device and Target app, instead of all processes available in the Target app's list. When I ran the Energy Log instrument by setting the Target device as my iPhone and Target app as my app, When I actively using means in foreground , the graphs are displaying looks like for my app activity. But I put the my app in background and leave the iphone ideal there also graphs are displaying correctly. But I used the other apps the GPU , Total CPU % are increasing drastically, please see next comment for my query.

Comment: I am getting confused whether that graphs are from my app activity or combined activity of my app(background/suspended state) and the active (foreground) app.Please clarify.I started my process to know battery drain from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609942/analyze-ios-app-power-usage